# Java Swing Variable Not Displaying, What can I do differently?

Tags: java, swing

So i had a question.. at the very bottom where it says //Decimal to binary it gives me an error saying that i cannot display my hold variable...the error is "The type of this expressing 'int' is not a reference type" Please help!

```
// The "RADIO_BUTTONGUI" class.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Color;
public class DecimalToBinary

{
    static JLabel leftTitle, rightTitle, leftInstruct, rightInstruct, decimal, binary;
    static JButton leftBtn, rightBtn;
    static JTextField leftInput, rightInput, leftAns, rightAns;
    static int decimalAns = 0;
    static int binaryAns = 0;
    static int decList[] = new int[]{128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};

    private static void guiApp ()
    {

        // rgb(41, 182, 246) blue
        // rgb(231, 76, 60) red

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Binary <=> Decimal Converter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (6, 2));
        panel.setBackground (new Color (44, 62, 80));



        leftTitle = new JLabel ("Binary 2 Decimal", JLabel.CENTER);
        leftTitle.setForeground (new Color (41, 182, 246));
        leftTitle.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 35));

        leftInstruct = new JLabel ("Enter an 8-digit binary number:", JLabel.CENTER);
        leftInstruct.setForeground (new Color (41, 182, 246));
        leftInstruct.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 15));

        leftInput = new JTextField ("");
        leftInput.setForeground (Color.black);
        leftInput.setBackground (new Color (41, 182, 246));
        leftInput.setHorizontalAlignment (JTextField.CENTER);
        leftInput.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));

        leftBtn = new JButton ("Convert to Decimal");
        leftBtn.setForeground (Color.black);
        leftBtn.setBackground (new Color (41, 182, 246));

        decimal = new JLabel ("Decimal Equivalent", JLabel.CENTER);
        decimal.setForeground (new Color (41, 182, 246));
        decimal.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));

        leftAns = new JTextField ("");
        leftAns.setBackground (new Color (41, 182, 246));
        leftAns.setForeground (Color.black);
        leftAns.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        leftAns.setHorizontalAlignment (JTextField.CENTER);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        rightTitle = new JLabel ("Decimal 2 Binary", JLabel.CENTER);
        rightTitle.setForeground (new Color (242, 4, 24));
        rightTitle.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 35));

        rightInstruct = new JLabel ("Enter a Decimal Number 0-255:", JLabel.CENTER);
        rightInstruct.setForeground (new Color (242, 4, 24));
        rightInstruct.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 15));
        rightInput = new JTextField ("");

        rightInput.setBackground (new Color (242, 4, 24));
        rightInput.setForeground (Color.white);
        rightInput.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        rightInput.setHorizontalAlignment (JTextField.CENTER);

        rightBtn = new JButton ("Convert to Binary");
        rightBtn.setForeground (Color.white);
        rightBtn.setBackground (new Color (242, 4, 24));

        binary = new JLabel ("Binenter code hereary Equivalent", JLabel.CENTER);
        binary.setForeground (new Color (242, 4, 24));
        binary.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));

        rightAns = new JTextField ("");
        rightAns.setForeground (Color.white);
        rightAns.setBackground (new Color (242, 4, 24));
        rightAns.setFont (new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        rightAns.setHorizontalAlignment (JTextField.CENTER);

        ButtonHandler onClick = new ButtonHandler ();
        leftBtn.addActionListener (onClick);
        rightBtn.addActionListener (onClick);

        panel.add (leftTitle);
        panel.add (rightTitle);
        panel.add (leftInstruct);
        panel.add (rightInstruct);
        panel.add (leftInput);
        panel.add (rightInput);
        panel.add (leftBtn);
        panel.add (rightBtn);
        panel.add (decimal);
        panel.add (binary);
        panel.add (leftAns);
        panel.add (rightAns);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane ();
        contentPane.add (panel);
        frame.setSize (600, 500);
        frame.setVisible (true);

    }


    private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            String command = e.getActionCommand ();
            final String value = leftInput.getText ();
            String binary = leftInput.getText ();
            int binAry = binary.length ();
            String decimal = rightInput.getText ();
            int decimalLength = decimal.length ();
            int hold = 0;

            for (int x = 0 ; x < 8 ; x++)
            {
                if (e.getSource () == leftBtn)
                {
                    if (binAry < 8 || binAry > 8)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You Must Only Enter An 8 Digit Number");

                    }
                    else if (value.charAt (x) == '1' || value.charAt (x) == '0')
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You May Only Enter 1 or 0");

                    }
                    else if (binAry == 8)
                    {
                        for (int i = 8 ; i < 0 ; i++)
                        {
                            if (value.substring (i, i + 1).equals ("1"))
                            {
                                hold += Math.pow (2, 7 - i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    leftAns.setText ("" + hold);
                }
            }

           //DECIMAL TO BINARY
           for(int x = 0; decimalLength > 8; x++)
           {
            hold = decimalLength% 2;
            hold /= 2;
           }
            decimalAns.setText("" + hold);

        }
    }








    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable ()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                guiApp ();
            }
        }


        );
    } // main method
} // RADIO_BUTTONGUI class
```

Comment: `decimalAns` is an `int`, so this: `decimalAns.setText("" + hold);` - makes no sense, as `int` doesn't have any methods

Comment: so how can i fix that? Any suggestions?

Comment: I "assume" you mean to use a `JLabel`, but that's just a guess - also beware, that it's impossible for your `for-loop` to exit when `decimalLength > 8` because `decimalLength` never changes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to invoke a method from the int class which has no methods. If you are trying to convert your `decimalAns` into String, try using `Integer.toString()`.

```
String theString = Integer.toString(decimalAns);
```

Comment: int class isn't even a class in that sense.